# How to catch that shiny is busy without user interaction

Tags: r, shiny

to know when shiny is busy I use `$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')`, my problem is that it seems like class "shiny-busy" is only triggered by user interaction (such as a button click).

If I have an output that will be display directly when I launch shiny, for example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"))

server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(5)
    hist(rnorm(100))
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

The html tag won't have the class "shiny-busy". To show that shiny is busy it needs an user interaction, a button for example :

```
ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("go", "Go"), 
                plotOutput("plot"))

server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$go > 0) {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      hist(rnorm(100))
    }
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

In my terminology, in the 1st case Shiny is busy b/c it hasn't display the output yet. But it hasn't the class "shiny-busy". I would like to know that shiny is "busy" at this moment, without using an user interaction.

Do you have any ideas of how I can achieve this ? Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is relevant to what we have been working on: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/930 I'll test your case later.

Comment: Do you want to test the develpment version of shiny? I just introduced some JavaScript events in it: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/935/files?short_path=36e8a69#diff-36e8a6943c0ca56eb1231883cfd3dd79